# Moving SQL Server between domains

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

If a Windows Server machine hosting SQL Server 2008 R2 is changed to another domain, what steps definitely and might need to be done for SQL Server before and after the new domain is joined?

Comment: The biggest issue we faced was all of the windows-based permissions after we left Domain A were invalid and we had to manually replace them all after logging on as `sa` after joining Domain B. This was about a year ago and I still find the occasional issue where I find another reference to an old Domain A user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a pretty extensive list.  See this answer to this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37583/moving-sql-server-to-different-domain/39000#39000

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to have a sysadmin or securityadmin that is not bound by any domain, eg. SA, and that they are allowed to logon:

```
SELECT l.name, l.denylogin, l.isntname, l.isntgroup, l.isntuser
FROM master.sys.syslogins l
WHERE l.sysadmin = 1 OR l.securityadmin = 1
ORDER BY l.isntgroup, l.isntname, l.isntuser
```

If you want to document all non sql local users in all databases you could use:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'select ''?'' as DB_name,name from ?.sys.sysusers where isntname=1'
```

Look at who is starting your sql services:

```
select servicename,service_account,startup_type_desc as StartupType from sys.dm_server_services
```

Check where the db files are, then check who can access them:

```
select db_name(database_id), name,physical_name from sys.master_files
```